# Why does index.html have priority over index.php?

Tags: php, apache

I have a website on a server. The homepage is example.com/index.php .

OK, I uploaded an index.html named file to the server (the root dir) and when I typed in my site's domain into the browser's URL bar, I was suprised, because the index.html page loaded.

(example.com->example.com/index.html) 
So not what I wanted.

My question:
Why did that happen? Why does index.html have advantage over index.php?

Comment: Because that's the way your server is set up. You can make certain files take priority over others. If you need help setting up your server, check out server fault instead. Post your configuration. Are you using apache, IIS? what?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It really depends on the Server you're using. This is a matter of configuration. It's not that there's any advantage from using html vs php filetype.

You could say that the `.html` variation takes precedence due to the fact that it's the most basic web format.

If you're using Apache, just check the default `.htaccess` setup:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.php index.htm default.html Default.htm default.html Default.html default.shtml Default.shtml page1.html index.pl index.cgi index.php3 index.phtml home.htm home.html home.shtml index.wml
```

You can edit that and make it fit your needs.

Comment: OK thanks for the answer... Is this related to the .htaccess file?

Comment: @kuroir i don't think he meant advantage like that, i think he meant it in a way that it has a certain priority. Your answer still works though.

Comment: Yes, you can define that from your `.htaccess` file. Look the updated answer.

Comment: @Matt I know, just making sure. Since some people still think that it has something to do with SEO ;)

Comment: @Akos: Yes, the `DirectoryIndex` directive can be changed in `.htaccess` files.

Comment: If your using WHM (CPanel Ver 106), visit Home -> Service Configuration -> Apache Configuration -> DirectoryIndex Priority. You will see a list of which extensions are used first. Add/Remove and adjust the order of directory index filenames.

Answer (score 14):

@kuroir is right, that depends on the web server configuration, in Apache it's the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.cgi
```

That will give priority to `.html` files over `.php` files, and priority to `.php` files over `.cgi` files.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old and has been accepted but I want to add to this in case someone else has this problem.

I came here when looking for a solution to the same problem.
Entering the Wordpress "index.php" into the URL got redirected to "index.html".
It had nothing to do with the .htaccess. I finally found the solution in their forum. Wordpress modified the program a couple years ago to strip "index.php" from URLs. So then of course it goes to your default (usually index.html).

To make it behave as you expect, you need to revert the change here:
[changeset 9203](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/9203). 
See [Forum topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/indexhtml)

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on your hosting provider well yes 90% hosting provider gives priority to index.html instead of index.php or any other extention.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue, as with all types of development, is maintenance.  If you decide to change technology then by exposing the file extension you are setting yourself up for a lot of work - not to mention the security aspects of broadcasting your choice.  The best situation is to avoid exposing extensions by using url rewriting.