# Load index.php as my First page in PHP

Tags: php, apache

how I can in my php project let the index.php be first page that my project load not index.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873634/why-does-index-html-have-priority-over-index-php

Comment: Chances are you actually want a solution for Apache, not PHP. Unless you're using IIS or something else?

Comment: The best way to get help is to be able to answer [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? Also, what research have you done? Research [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a well explained answer, to do what the OP is asking you must use `DirectoryIndex` in Apache. In the site configuration, or .htaccess, you must put the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This alone tells apache to launch `index.php` as your main file. So loading `domain.tld/` it really loads `index.php`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

This will load `index.php` but if that does not exist, it will try to load `index.html`. The order of the files listed is what apache looks for first.

More details [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via `htaccess`

Write following code in your `htaccess` file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for `DirectoryIndex` in your apache.conf and make sure that index.php comes before index.html. Like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
```

You also can add this line to your .htaccess file if you don't have access to the apche config or don't want to set this globally