# My empy index.php file is crashing my site

Tags: php, mysql

My site http://devoffpod.purplebottlemedia.com/ isn't pulling the index.html file when adding an empty index.php file to my server. As soon as I remove the index.php file from the server my site pulls correctly. Does any one have any suggestions to why this might be happening?

Comment: Yeah. It's supposed to be that way if you configure your webserver that way (or it came preconfigured).

Comment: Looks like the response is empty. In other words, you website finishes doing something but doesn't return anything back.

Comment: Is your server configured to run PHP Scripts ? What does <?php phpinfo (); ?> show ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I believe that would prompt the server to give the file to you as a download...

Comment: Suggestion: don't place an index.php file in your web root.

Comment: Returning an empty response is not the same thing as "crashing."  If you put an empty index file on the server and you get back an empty response, then that means it's successfully serving the empty index file. If you don't want it to serve that file, don't put it there.

Comment: Try putting "Echo 'something'" at the top before anything happens.

Comment: I forget where, but in Apache's config, there's a setting that tells it which "index" files to load.  Presumably, it has `php` before `html`.

Comment: See [Why does index.html have priority over index.php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873634/why-does-index-html-have-priority-over-index-php)

Comment: Response header: `
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Server:Apache` So yeah.

Comment: @FabienTheSolution: That's what I was thinking of! :-D

Comment: I want the file to be served for sure. I had originally added code to call if mobile display a mobile.html page. Adding that code worked and successfully redirected the site on mobile. It's just when using my desktop that it doesn't load. I tried putting the file in a sub folder but the problem I'm having when doing that is my site doesn't redirect on mobile.

Comment: Would it note pull correctly if the site is being hosted on a sub domain?

Answer (score 5):

Servers that support PHP are usually configured to look for an `index.php` before they look for an `index.html`.

You have an `index.php` so it is being served.

Servers don't check to see if an index file has any content before serving it.

Answer (score 1):

try to insert .htaccess (text file) in the principal directory

with this code at the inner

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. I'm wondering if the problem is the site being hosted on a sub domain.