# hide img folder content

Tags: php, html

is there a way to avoid a user from viewing the content of my website img folder ? 
For example if a visitor inspect the site with google chrome devtools, I don't want to show the content of the website img folder

NOTE: with directory listing I am able to hide the content of my img folder by visiting the url: wwwmysite.com/img --> FORBIDDEN but inspecting the site with the devtools the content of the img folder is still visible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5932641/80836 - deny directory listing with htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deny directory listing with htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess)

Comment: with directory listing I am able to hide the content of my img folder by visiting the url: wwwmysite.com/img --> FORBIDDEN but inspecting the site with the devtools the content of the img folder is still visible

Answer (score 1):

Add a index.html in image folder, like this people won't be able to see all the content of the folder.

Comment: done but I still can see all the images inside my img folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about uploads, then the solution is quite simple: you put the upload folder outside `DOMCUMENT_ROOT`. Kinda like what are (or should be) doing from your PHP code.

Then you set up `.htaccess` to load all uploaded images though a PHP file.

And when you have such a setup, you can also start adding additional security features, like checking a cookies, before loading an image, if the user accessed the "parent html page", before loading the image and other solutions.

---

Alternatively, if all you want to stop is directory listing, you just use `Options -Indexes` in your webserver's config.

Answer (score 0):

If index.html won't work try rename it to default.html or maybe to main.html.
Actually you can look at the server configuration.

Maybe this will assist you:
[Why does index.html have priority over index.php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873634/why-does-index-html-have-priority-over-index-php)